# PCB maximum trace current in a power amplifier

Tags: power, amplifier, pcb-design

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tpa3123d2) for the TPA3123 lists the IC as a HTSSOP package. I am using this to drive two 20W 6 ohm speakers in a stereo configuration, with the IC powered from a 24V 3.2A power supply.

With the formula \$I=\sqrt{\frac{W}{Ω}}\$ the current drawn by each speaker at maximum power is 1.82A, or about 2 amperes. The largest trace I can fit onto one TSSOP-24 pad can carry 1.3A, however the speaker is driven by two types of outputs, BSL and LOUT(BSR and ROUT for right speaker).

Am I right to assume current is 'shared' across the two pins as is with the 4 VCC pins(labelled PVCCx)? By current 'sharing' I mean that the xSL and xOUT pins do not source the full 2A, for each speaker, instead a portion that adds up to full power when both source currents are added together.

Comment: The peak voltage across 6 Ohms at 20 Watts is 15.5 Volts. That's over 2.5 Amps, peak. The rms value is what you wrote. Are we on the same page so far? Also, is that a bridged IC?

Comment: Carry capability of a PCB trace is a stretchable concept and depends on trace segment length and proximity to massive copper areas. Please share your layout for better assessment of the community. And why don't you just copy exactly the recommended board layout and be worry-free and happy?

Comment: @ale..chenski There is no recommended board layout specified on the datasheet, only guidelines for decoupling capacitor arrangement and grounding.

Comment: @periblepsis the IC can be configure in either BTL or SE. for this application it is SE. forgot that 20W was the RMS power, should the PCB traces be adjusted to 3A combined?

Comment: @lemon If single ended, then you need more than 24 V. At least 31 V, and that's assuming an ideal world we don't live in. So I'd say 35 V for the single rail. I'm weak on power PCB design, so I'll leave that to others.

Comment: @lemon have a look at the layout of their evaluation module: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slou208